# GMT subtraction on MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab

I'm currently working on a small project on handling time difference on MATLAB. I have two input files; `Time_in and Time_out`. The two files contain arrays of time in the format e.g `2315 (GMT - Hours and Minute)`

I've read both `Time_in' and 'Time_out` on MATLAB but I don't know how to perform the subtraction. Also, I want the corresponding answers to be in minutes domain only e.g (2hrs 30mins = 150minutes)

Comment: Can you please give us a complete example? how did you read the two time vectors? what are their variable type in MATLAB?

Comment: Read the time vectors as strings. Would 'double' be better?

Comment: see my answer: `datenum` is the best way to handle date or time vectors/strings

Comment: this is a very well documented question on matlab docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is one of several possible solutions:

First, you should convert your time strings to a MATLAB serial date number. If you've done this, you can do your calculation as you want:

```
% input time as string
time_in = '2115';
time_out = '2345';

% read the input time as datenum
dTime_in = datenum(time_in,'HHMM');
dTime_out = datenum(time_out,'HHMM');

% subtract to get the time difference
timeDiff = abs(dTime_out - dTime_in);

% Get the minutes of the time difference
timeout = timeDiff * 24 * 60;
```

Furthermore, to calculate the time differences correctly you also should put some information about the date in your time vector, in order to calculate the correct time around midnight.

If you need further information about the function `datenum` you should read the following part of the MATLAB documentation:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Any questions?

Comment: How do I make time_in and time_out to be input files where I can store arrays of number. I've tried but 'datenum' is giving error regarding strings of array

Also, I want the timeout answer to be an array of numbers too which is the final solution.

Thank you

Comment: Can you make an example of you Strings?

Comment: This is what i added to the previous code

fid = fopen('time_in.txt','r');
fid2 = fopen('time_out.txt','r');
t_in = fscanf(fid);
fclose (fid);
t_out = fscan(fid2)
fclose (fid2);

Answer (score 0):

In a recent version of MATLAB, you could use `textscan` together with `datetime` and `duration` data types to do this.

```
% read the first file
fh1 = fopen('Time_in');
d1  = textscan(fh1, '%{HHmm}D');
fclose(fh1);
fh2 = fopen('Time_out');
d2  = textscan(fh2, '%{HHmm}D');
fclose(fh2);
```

Note the format specifier `'%{HHmm}D'` tells MATLAB to read the 4-digit string into a `datetime` array.

`d1` and `d2` are now `cell` arrays where the only element is a `datetime` vector. You can subtract these, and then use the `minutes` function to find the number of minutes.

```
result = minutes(d2{1} - d1{1})
```